# Problem with touch events-trying to centre the image to touch

Tags: javascript, html, css, touch-event

So the problem I am facing is that I want to centre my image to the touch that will drag it.
e.g.
If the user touches the top right corner of the image, the image will automatically move so its centre is on that touch instead.

With the code

```
img.style.left = e.touches[0].clientX +"px";
img.style.top = e.touches[0].clientX - shiftX +"px";
```

not working.

Here is the full code of the touch start event:

```
        img.addEventListener('touchstart', function(e) {
          beingDragged = img;
          start = e.target.parentNode.id;
          img.style.zIndex = 1;
          shiftX = e.touches[0].clientX-(img.width/2);
          shiftY = e.touches[0].clientY - (img.height/2);//code for dragging the image in the later touchmove event
          img.style.left = e.touches[0].clientX +"px";
          img.style.top = e.touches[0].clientY +"px";
        });
```

note doing this

```
img.style.left = e.touches[0].clientX - shiftX +"px";
img.style.top = e.touches[0].clientY - shiftY +"px";
```

and this

```
img.style.left = e.touches[0].clientX - img.getBoundingClientRect().left;
img.style.top = e.touches[0].clientY - img.getBoundingClientRect().top;
```

also hasn't worked for me.
The touch move function works fine just this minor problem with touchstart.

The image's css

```
img{
  position: absolute;
  width: 90%;
  height: 90%;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```